# Is it possible to use Console.ReadLine() more than once?

Tags: c#, console.readline

Is there any way that I can make this program display both text by using Console.ReadLine(); twice?

I provided my code below and whenever I debug I only get the ones provided above the first one, but when I remove the first Console.ReadLine(); everything gets displayed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyFirstProject
     {
         class Program
             {
                static void Main(string[] args)
                     {

        String name= "John Berr"; 
        String country = "USA";
        String city = "Unknown";
        String age = "15"; 

        Console.WriteLine("My name is " + name);
        Console.WriteLine("The Country I reside in is " + country);
        Console.WriteLine("The city I reside in is " + city);
        Console.WriteLine("I am " + age +" years old");
        Console.ReadLine();


        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You realize that `Console.ReadLine()` waits for input? run your program, and hit return in the console window.

Comment: Alright, I'm going to try that! I wish I could upvote you, but my rep is low.

Comment: @redbrand12 You have also requested your account to be deleted?

Comment: Yeah, last week... Let me go change that!

Comment: Everyone who helped out, I just want to thank all of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try put them in a while loop:

```
var c = "c";

while (c == "c")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    Console.WriteLine("press 'c' to continue");
    c = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I'll copy and paste so that I can see how the code works though!

Comment: I just started today! I need some good books that'll help. I'll google that

Comment: I thumbed you up since I agree! I'm going to wake up early in the morning and work on some c#. I'll return with better questions than this! Thanks for the help